# What are good references to learn how to model heterostructures using DFT?

Tags: density-functional-theory, reference-request, heterostructures

I am interested in modeling heterostructures using DFT. What are some good references to start learning?

Comment: What type of calculation do you want to do?

Comment: Dan: This question was closed probably because you didn't answer the question in the comment for 3 days. We can re-open the question if you could add a *little* bit more detail!

Comment: Any additional detail you can give on this? Based on the upvotes, it seems like a question the community could be interested in, but there just isn't enough context in the question yet to provide a good answer.